# Regex to get two values in string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string:

```
<http://test.host/users?param1=1&param=1>; rel=\"rel_value\"
```

And I would like to get the URL and the rel value. That is:

`http://test.host/users?param1=1&param=1`

and

`rel_value`

I know how to get the URL:

`string[/<.*?>/]`

But failing to see how to get the rel. Any ideas on a regex that I could get both?

Comment: Does the string actually contain those backslashes?

Comment: yes it does contain those backslashes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string is guaranteed to have that format:

```
/<(.+)>; rel=\\\"(.+)\\\"/
```

To be used like so:

```
m = s.match(/<(.+)>; rel=\\\"(.+)\\\"/)
m[0] #=> http://test.host/users?param1=1&param=1
m[1] #=> rel_value
```

Additionally, you could just use two regexes to search for each thing in the string:

```
s[/(?<=<).+(?=>)/] #=> http://test.host/users?param1=1&param=1
s[/(?<=rel=\\\").+(?=\\\")/] #=> rel_value
```

(These use lookahead and lookbehind to not capture anything besides the values).

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for a regex that does both:

```
<(.*)>.*rel=\\"(.*)\\"
```

The first capturing group contains the URL, and the second one the rel value. But you could just do one regex for each.
For the URL:

```
<(.*)>
```

And for the rel value:

```
rel=\\"(.*)\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be at least one non-regex solution:

```
str.tr('<>\\\"','').split(';\s+rel=')
  #=> ["http://test.host/users?param1=1&param=1; rel=rel_value"]
```